# React Native Combine line and bar in a chart

Tags: react-native, charts

Is there any plugin which can combine line and bars into a chart for react native?

like: [image]

Answer (score 0):

There's an awesome charting library in react-native named [react-native-gifted-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-charts) which seamlessly handles combining bar and line charts. You just need to pass a prop named `showLine` to the `<BarChart>` component.
You can see the [official documentation about the combined Bar and Line chart](https://gifted-charts.web.app/barchart/#combinedBarLine). 
Also, there is a similar question on Stack Overflow - [I want to create chart which combine line and bar chart in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70750796/7533126).

The only difference in your question is that the data points for the Line chart are not aligned with the Bar chart's data. *react-native-gifted-charts* allows you to use a separate data array for the combined line chart with the help of `lineData` prop.

Below is the code for your chart-

```js
export const BarLine = props => {
  const data = [
    {value: 12},
    {value: 4},
    {value: 18},
    {value: 16},
    {value: 5},
    {value: 11},
    {value: 16},
    {value: 5},
    {value: 11},
  ];

  const lineValuesArray = [
    22, 25, 29, 28, 26, 20, 24, 22, 23, 18, 21, 22, 28, 27, 30,
  ];
  const lineData = lineValuesArray.map((item, index) => ({
    value: item,
    customDataPoint:
      (index + 1) % 3 == 0
        ? () => (
            <View
              style={{
                height: 18,
                width: 18,
                borderRadius: 9,
                backgroundColor: '#42F19E',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}>
              <View
                style={{
                  height: 6,
                  width: 6,
                  borderRadius: 3,
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                }}
              />
            </View>
          )
        : () => {},
  }));

  return (
    <BarChart
      data={data}
      noOfSections={3}
      maxValue={30}
      barWidth={16}
      spacing={40}
      initialSpacing={0}
      roundedTop
      showGradient
      frontColor={'#00C4F5'}
      gradientColor={'#7A4FD1'}
      xAxisType={ruleTypes.DASHED}
      xAxisColor={'gray'}
      rulesColor={'gray'}
      yAxisThickness={0}
      hideYAxisText
      showLine
      lineData={lineData}
      lineConfig={{
        curved: true,
        color: '#42F19E',
        thickness: 4,
        spacing: 6,
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

The output of the above code is- 
[image: output chart]

Answer (score -2):

You can use [react-native-chart-kit](https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit).

There is no component that can do exactly what you need, so 2 different kinds of charts in one. What you could do though, is have two different charts, one for lines and one for bars. You place them on the same position, one above the other. That way you basically have two charts looking like one, with both lines and bars.