# I want to create chart which combine line and bar chart in react native,

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bar-chart, linechart

Here is the attached image of design, I am new to react native please help me to create this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vB9b.png)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to combine separate Bar and Line charts can be hectic and buggy. Instead, you should use a chart library that has support for combined bar and line charts.  
For react-native, I have developed a charting library named [react-native-gifted-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-charts). It allows you to add Lines to Bar charts, just by passing a prop called `showLine`. You can see the [official documentation about combined Bar and Line chart](https://gifted-charts.web.app/barchart/#combinedBarLine). 
Here is an example- 
Let's say your data is - `[15,30,26,40]`
You can render a Bar chart with Line using the following code-

```js
const barData = [{value: 15}, {value: 30}, {value: 26}, {value: 40}];
return <BarChart data={barData} showLine />;
```

The output is- 
 [image: simple Line in Bar]

We need to make the line curved and shift it upwards. The line can be customised using the `lineConfig` prop as shown below-

```js
const barData = [{value: 15}, {value: 30}, {value: 26}, {value: 40}];

return (
  <BarChart
    data={barData}
    showLine
    lineConfig={{curved: true, shiftY: 20}} />
);
```

The output now is- 
[image: curved Line in Bar shifted upwards]

Now that we are sorted about combining line and bar charts in react-native, let's try to render [the chart that you have provided with your question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vB9b.png). The next major challenge in your chart is to make the top of each bar *triangular* in shape. This can be achieved by adding the property `topLabelComponent` to each object in the data array.

The complete code for your chart will be-

```js
export const CombinedBarLineChart = () => {

  const Triangle = props => {
    return (
      <View
        style={[
          triangleStyles.triangleCorner,
          props.style,
          {
            borderRightWidth: props.width / 2,
            borderTopWidth: props.width / 2,
            borderTopColor: props.color,
          },
        ]}
      />
    );
  };

  const TopLabel = ({color, label}) => (
    <>
      <Triangle
        width={70}
        color={color}
        style={{
          transform: [{rotate: '45deg'}, {translateX: 12}, {translateY: 13}],
        }}
      />
      <Text style={{position: 'absolute', top: 4, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
        {'+' + label.toFixed(1)}
      </Text>
    </>
  );

  const iData: Array<itemType> = [
    {value: 12.2, frontColor: '#DAEFF8'},
    {value: 35.7, frontColor: '#C0ECFB'},
    {value: 68.2, frontColor: '#87E0FE'},
    {value: 111.5, frontColor: '#39CCFC'},
    {value: 167.0, frontColor: '#009ACD'},
  ];

  iData.forEach(
    (item,index) =>
      (item.topLabelComponent = () => (
        <TopLabel color={item.frontColor} label={index ? item.value-iData[index-1].value : item.value} />
      )),
  );

  return (
    <BarChart
      barWidth={50}
      spacing={14}
      initialSpacing={10}
      maxValue={260}
      stepHeight={30}
      data={iData}
      rulesType={ruleTypes.SOLID}
      xAxisThickness={0}
      yAxisThickness={0}
      hideYAxisText
      showLine
      lineConfig={{
        curved: true,
        thickness: 3,
        dataPointsColor: '#39CCFC',
        dataPointsRadius: 6,
        color: 'gray',
        shiftY: 56,
      }}
    />
  );
};

const triangleStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  triangleCorner: {
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    transform: [{rotate: '90deg'}],
  },
});
```

The final output of the above code is- 
[image: final output]

Answer (score -2):

You can use [react-native-chart-kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart-kit) to create BarChart

you need to install

```
yarn add react-native-chart-kit

yarn add react-native-svg //install peer dependencies
```

you need these file to import

```
import {
   LineChart,
   BarChart,
   PieChart,
   ProgressChart,
   ContributionGraph,
   StackedBarChart
 } from "react-native-chart-kit";
```

**Quick Example**

```
 <View>
   <Text>Bezier Line Chart</Text>
   <LineChart
     data={{
       labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
       datasets: [
         {
           data: [
             Math.random() * 100,
             Math.random() * 100,
             Math.random() * 100,
             Math.random() * 100,
             Math.random() * 100,
             Math.random() * 100
           ]
         }
       ]
     }}
     width={Dimensions.get("window").width} // from react-native
     height={220}
     yAxisLabel="$"
     yAxisSuffix="k"
     yAxisInterval={1} // optional, defaults to 1
     chartConfig={{
       backgroundColor: "#e26a00",
       backgroundGradientFrom: "#fb8c00",
       backgroundGradientTo: "#ffa726",
       decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
       color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
       labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
       style: {
         borderRadius: 16
      },
       propsForDots: {
         r: "6",
         strokeWidth: "2",
         stroke: "#ffa726"
       }
     }}
     bezier
     style={{
       marginVertical: 8,
       borderRadius: 16
     }}
   />
 </View>
```

For further Details you can check [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart-kit) .

It will Helpful.

Comment: Will this work in expo also?

Comment: Yes you can use it for Expo also.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try this

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to combine chart types at all...